# Create a new model which have all fields of currently existing model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am having a model `Player` with my django app .

```
class Player(models.Model):
    """ player model """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    bookmark_url = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
```

As per my requirement i need to create a new model `BookmarkPlayer`which will have all fields of `Player` model.

Right now i have two things into my mind to do this .

1. I can extend Player class for BookmarkPlayer model.

```
    class BookmarkPlayer(Player):
        """ just a bookmark player"""
        class Meta:
            app_label = "core"
```

2. I can define all fields of Player model into BookmarkPlayer model.

```
     class BookmarkPlayer(models.Model):
            """ bookmark player model """
            name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
            date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
            last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
            hash = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
            bookmark_url = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
```

I just want to know which way is  better to do this .Please share with my if there is another good way.

***Updated Question***

Knbb's idea to  create a base class is interesting but i am facing issue with one of my model which is already existed into database.

**My actual models :**

```
class Address(models.Model):
    address = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)


class Site(models.Model):
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Player(models.Model):
    # ... other fields
    shipping_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name='shipping')
    billing_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name='billing')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    site = models.ManyToManyField(Site, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
       abstract = True
```

**Models after changes  :**

```
class Address(models.Model):
    address = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)


class Site(models.Model):
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class BasePlayer(models.Model):
    # .. other fields
    shipping_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name='shipping')
    billing_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name='billing')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    site = models.ManyToManyField(Site, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
       abstract = True

class Player(BasePlayer):
   class Meta:
       app_label = 'core'


class BookmarkPlayer(BasePlayer):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'core'
```

After these changes when i am running my django server i am getting errors given below.

```
django.core.management.base.CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
core.test1: Accessor for field 'shipping_address' clashes with related field 'Address.shipping'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'shipping_address'.
core.test1: Reverse query name for field 'shipping_address' clashes with related field 'Address.shipping'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'shipping_address'.
core.test1: Accessor for field 'billing_address' clashes with related field 'Address.billing'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'billing_address'.
core.test1: Reverse query name for field 'billing_address' clashes with related field 'Address.billing'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'billing_address'.
core.test2: Accessor for field 'shipping_address' clashes with related field 'Address.shipping'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'shipping_address'.
core.test2: Reverse query name for field 'shipping_address' clashes with related field 'Address.shipping'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'shipping_address'.
core.test2: Accessor for field 'billing_address' clashes with related field 'Address.billing'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'billing_address'.
core.test2: Reverse query name for field 'billing_address' clashes with related field 'Address.billing'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'billing_address'
```

**Answer :**
Finally i got answer if we are using the related_name attribute on a ForeignKey or ManyToManyField into a Abstract model.
This would normally cause a problem in abstract base classes, since the fields on this class are included into each of the child classes, with exactly the same values for the attributes (including related_name) each time .
To work around this problem, when you are using related_name in an abstract base class (only), part of the name should contain '%(app_label)s' and '%(class)s'.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes
Now my BasePlayer model is

```
class BasePlayer(models.Model):
    # .. other fields
    shipping_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_shipping')
    billing_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_billing')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    site = models.ManyToManyField(Site, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
       abstract = True
```

Comment: There are several other, better ways to do this, but it depends on your exact requirements which one is the best. What's the reason you want two models in the first place?

Comment: I want to bookmark Player details so i can share the session between users at my website.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you basically want to copy the details of a `Player` at a particular moment and save it as a `BookmarkPlayer`? In that case, see my answer, that would be the best way. It's also easy to add some convenience methods to convert a `Player` to a `BookmarkPlayer` and the other way around.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If your `BookmarkPlayer` needs the same data but in a different table, an abstract base model is the best way to go:

```
class BasePlayer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    bookmark_url = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Player(BasePlayer):
    """ player model """
    pass

class BookmarkPlayer(BasePlayer):
    """ bookmark player model """
    pass
```

This way, both `Player` and `BookmarkPlayer` inherit their fields from the `BasePlayer` model, but because `BasePlayer` is abstract, the models are completely decoupled.

Multi-table inheritance on the other hand would still save the fields in a single table, but add an extra table for the `BookmarkPlayer` with an implicit `OneToOneField` to the `Player` table.

Comment: i tried as per your suggetion to create a Baseclass of abstract nature but by using this i am not able to validate my model .Please see updated question

Comment: Just curious in the end result, how this differs from creating the Player model and inheriting it in your Bookmark Player? Still learning about abstract models but they seem like they would accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

There are some good info about model inheritance here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

Option 2 will introduce duplication, which is always bad. If `BookmarkPlayer` will not have any new fields, only different methods, I would suggest you use the "proxy model" option described in the link, since you don't need `BookmarkPlayer` to have it's own table in the database.

If it needs it's own table, "Multi-table inhertiance" is the way to go, which would be option 1 in your question

Comment: BookmarkPlayer needs to have it's own table into database.

Comment: @PrashantGaur I updated the answer to cover that scenario as well

Comment: @knbk is of course right, Multi-table inheritance will only save the extra `BookmarkPlayer` fields in a new table. His answer is better :)

Comment: @PrashantGaur I guess changing the related_name to something different is worth trying. But it validated on my machine. Which django version are you on?

Comment: I am using Django1.3 .Please see update in my question .I got why the error was coming .